# You've earned the "反対投票する" privilege! Learn more about it in the help center

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange, privileges

Yesterday I have obtained the "vote down" privilege. Some days ago I have obtained this privilege in other site of StackExchange, too.

But today I see this. The URL is correct and send to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down), but... what's happened?

[image]

Comment: You seem to have obtained the secret TeX.SX priviledge to write some Chinese(???) characters in unicode font. Ask Joseph Wright about this ;-) (Ok, this comment is completely off-topic)... *Strange bug it is, mmmh* Yoda would say ;-)

Comment: @joseph-wright, it seems that I have need your help. Now the site is all right, as yesterday. I have obtain this "secret priviledge" only for a morning.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be mentioned on MSE. However, a similar bug appeared couple days ago with Portuguese. This is probably of similar origin and shouldn't be persistent.

Comment: Do not worry. This is a minor bug (the URL was - and is - correct and now I do not see it more). I have reported it only because I do not knew if was a general problem.

Comment: This is (mostly) a caching problem. We have a fix in mind, will try it out soon.

Comment: As I have said, now the site works well for me. I hope it's so for all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internationalization seems to be the [Vietnam of Stack Exchange Network](http://blog.codinghorror.com/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science/).

A fix has been pushed out and we've even improved the tools a bit, so hopefully this won't happen again<sup>*</sup>.

<sub>* I'm not betting on that, though :)</sub>

Comment: Ok, and thank you for your answer. But, why "Vietnam"? Google Translate says that this is Japanese and its translation is "Against vote".

Comment: "Vietnam" here refers to the [Vietnam War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnam_War) and how it was deemed "un-winnable"; I'm using it because now that we've done [i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization#Naming), we're constantly finding bugs, breaking things, and adding overhead.

Comment: Ah! Only now I have understood. :-) Thanks.